# PDFkit cannot read html to convert to pdf (the html file exists)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pdfkit, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

**NOTE: Using Python.**
I am trying to convert a html to pdf using the **pdfkit.from_file** command.
Here are my inputs:

```
html_path="abfss://container@DataLakeName.dfs.core.windows.net/user/trusted-service-user/for_html/htmltest.html"
pdf_path = "abfss://container@DataLakeName.dfs.core.windows.net/user/trusted-service-user/for_html/htmltest.pdf"
```

Command I am using:

```
        pdfkit.from_file(html_path, pdf_path, options = myoptions)
```

My output is:

```
 No such file: abfss://container@DataLakeName.dfs.core.windows.net/user/trusted-service-user/for_html/htmltest.html
```

**For context:**
Just before this, I had put the html file there using **mssparkutils.fs.put()**. So the system can WRITE it, but not able to READ it? That's confusing.

**Other things I have tried:**

```
pdfkit.from_string()
pdfkit.from_url()
```

Errors they gave:

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that you are able to write the file but not able to read. It means there is no issue with mounting the storage account on Databricks.
The error `No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''"` indicates that you need to install `WKHTMLTOPDF` binaries:

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

For more related details, you can visit https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Thank you for your response. The WKHTMLTOPDF is part of the requirement.txt file in the workspace. So this is installed when the cluster starts in Azure Synapse. Also note: I am not using databricks and nothing is mounted. I am using Azure Synapse and it has a default storage account of Azure Data Lake Storage gen2. Any more advise?